# How to run a job in an Azure DevOps pipeline multiple times with different variable groups?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a job  with some steps in an Azure DevOps pipeline that I want to run multiple times, each time with a different variable group. Here is a minimal example:

```yaml
strategy:
  matrix:
    Customer:
      variableGroupName: 'Customer variables'
    Test:
      variableGroupName: 'Test variables'

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
- group: $(variableGroupName)

steps:
- script: echo $(MyVariable)
```

However, it yields this error when trying to run the pipeline:

> An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. Variable group  was not found or is not authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.

How can I change the configuration so that the variable group name gets set differently each run?

Comment: Now you have slightly different issue. Either your variable's value "variableGroupName" is not resolved, or pipeline does not have access to it. I would bet for the first option. It is simply to check - replace `$(variableGroupName)` by plain string (name of the variable group).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I find useful in these scenarios is a for each loop over the items I have, in your case a collection of variable groups.

Here's an updated code snippet:

```
parameters:
  # Define the variable groups to use
  - name: variableGroups
    type: object
    default:
      - name: "Customer"
        variableGroupName: "Customer variables"
      - name: "Test"
        variableGroupName: "Test variables"

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

stages:
  - stage: "test_stage"
    jobs:
      # Run the job for each variable group
      - ${{ each variableGroup in parameters.variableGroups }}:
          - job: "run_for_each_${{ variableGroup.name }}_variable_group_job"
            displayName: "Using ${{ upper(variableGroup.name) }} variable group"
            variables:
              - group: ${{ variableGroup.variableGroupName }}
            steps:
              - script: echo $(MyVariable)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what [Robert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76465502/595990) wrote, I ended up with this solution:

```yaml
parameters:
- name: variableGroups
  type: object
  default:
  - name: 'Azure'
    variableGroupName: 'MyApplication Azure'
    displayName: 'Azure'
  - name: 'Customer_Test'
    variableGroupName: 'MyApplication Customer Test'
    displayName: 'Customer Test'
  - name: 'Customer_Prod'
    variableGroupName: 'MyApplication Customer Prod'
    displayName: 'Customer Prod'

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

stages:
- stage: 'Build'
  jobs:
  - ${{ each variableGroup in parameters.variableGroups }}:
    - job: '${{ variableGroup.name }}'
      displayName: '${{ variableGroup.displayName }}'
      variables:
      - group: ${{ variableGroup.variableGroupName }}
      steps:
      - script: echo $(MyVariable)
```

I'm marking his answer as the accepted answer. But just for the sake of completeness, my code is here as well. I changed the indentation, added a `displayName` property to the `variableGroups`, and I don't think `${{ environment.name }}` worked for me so I changed the name of the jobs.